# Mental/psychiatric illnesses/disorders: natural or social kinds?

Tags: mental-illness

- What is *the* stance (i.e., that which is most prevalent across the psych "community" —both research and applied) on whether mental illnesses are inventions, discoveries, or some combination thereof?
- Is there or has there been much debate or critical analysis on this; if so, by or between whom, when, and to what affect on the field?

Comment: When I first saw your question it seemed frivolous. But I soon realized that you are asking a very important question. I don't have time to review the literature, but I can give you my short answer: _both_. The degree to which a specific disorder is a discovery or an invention varies. Schizophrenia is more discovery; specific personality disorders are more invention. The [Research Domain Criteria (RDoC)](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/research/research-funded-by-nimh/rdoc/index.shtml) approach seeks to _discover_ mental illnesses.

Comment: Rather that 'discoveries' or 'inventions', an alternative is 'description' or 'classification'.  My understanding is that all of the personality disorders (DSM5/ICD11) are observed patterns of behaviour that are common enough to warrant description and distinction from other common patterns of behaviour.  For example, there is a sufficient minority of individuals with delusions, hallucinations, and disorganised thinking to warrant the label 'scitzophrenia'. When a future Nobel laureate identifies the cause of scitzophrenia, then we will have a discovery.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question is explicitly soliciting opinions, which is off-topic for this forum.  However, it is an interesting question, so if it can be phrased in such a way as to be specific about what sort of evidence can be used to answer it, then please edit it accordingly, and then it can be reopened.